# SQL Query on Parent Include Child on EF

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, ria

I am working on Silverlight with C# using [RIA Services - MVVM pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2011/04/29/mvvm-pattern-for-ria-services.aspx). When I try to get records from `Orders` and `OrdersDetails` I get this error below:

> 'Notes' is not a member of
>   'Transient.collection[XXX.SilverLight.Web.Models.OrderDetails(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'.
> To
>   extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate
>   over the collection. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 58.

Here is my query:

```
public IQueryable<Order> AdvancedSearchOrder(string condition)
{
    ObjectQuery<Order> myQuery = new ObjectQuery<Order>("Orders", DbContext.ObjectContext()).Include("OrderDetails");
    if (condition != "")
    {
        myQuery = myQuery.Where(condition);
    }
    return myQuery;
}
```

In this case, I have

```
condition = "( (it.CustomerName like 'test')  )  and  ( (it.OrderDetails.Notes like 'testnote') )";
```

When I set it to

```
condition = "( (it.CustomerName like 'test')  )";
```

then, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `it.OrderDetails` as a set, which it likely isn't given that it has a plural name.  I'm going to infer that your data model is each `Order` has one or more `OrderDetail` records.  The *list* of `OrderDetail` objects doesn't have a `Notes` property.  An individual `OrderDetail` does.  I'm not sure of the RIA syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
condition = "( (it.CustomerName like 'test')  )  and  ( 
      (it.OrderDetails.Notes.Any(n => n.Contains('testnote') 
)";
```